# How to create an array in JSF EL?

Tags: jsp, jsf, el

I want create an array in JSF EL. How can I do that? Is it even possible?

To illustrate what I am trying:

```
<rich:pickList addAllText="" addText="" removeAllText="" removeText="">
    <f:selectItems value="#{'Test', 'TestTest', 'TestTestTest'}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're on EL 3.0 or newer, you can [construct collections directly in EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el004.htm).

```html
<f:selectItems value="#{['Test','TestTest','TestTestTest']}" />
```

If you're not on EL 3.0 yet, you could solve *this particular case* with a [`fn:split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) trick.

```html
<html ... xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">
...
<f:selectItems value="#{fn:split('Test,TestTest,TestTestTest', ',')}" />
```

Either way, this requires a minimum of JSF 2.0 for the support of `List<T>` in `<f:selectItems>`.

Comment: Or, if using JSF 2, add Omnifaces to the project and use `of:createArray` :)

Comment: Great, this works, although I had to use `xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions` instead of `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core`.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with EL 3.0:

```
[1, 2, 3].toArray()
```

This creates a List first, and then converts it to an array.

At least with recent JSF versions you don't even need an array for `f:selectItems`, any Iterable will do. So:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{['Test', 'TestTest', 'TestTestTest']}" />
```

For more information about collection construction in EL see the [EL 3.0 Specification - final release](https://java.net/projects/el-spec/downloads), 2.2 Construction of Collection Objects.

Answer (score 1):

I am using ArrayUtils from apache to do this.
first, register the ArrayUtils class as a bean so you can access it from EL.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>arrayUtils</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

then you can call ArrayUtils' methods:

```
#{myBean.aMethod(arrayUtils.add(ArrayUtils.EMPTY_INT_ARRAY, 1))}
```

the above code will not work if you can't access the constant EMPTY_INT_ARRAY. To this, i used primefaces p:importConstants component, not sure if can be done in plain JSF.

this is how i use it:

```
<p:importConstants type="org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils" var="ArrayUtils" />
```